# How can i make function call from one contract deployed on the blockchain to another contract seperately deployed on the blockchain?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

How can i make function call from one contract deployed on the blockchain to another contract seperately deployed on the blockchain to transfer ownership from the second (called) contract to a new address or contractaddress?

Hi!

So i deployed a tokencontract with the msg.sender address as the owner.

After i deployed the crowdsale contract (which needs ownership of the tokencontract to mint, burn and transact tokens) and i used the function transferOwnership() to transfer the token ownership to the crowdsale contract address.

This works, but then i need to change it back to another address, of course, it does not.

I need to have a function that directly calls the token contract address and gives as a parameter the new owner address.

How should i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the token contract in a state variable called `token`, it would simply look something like this:

```
function transferTokenOwnership(address newOwner) public {
    // check msg.sender here to make sure it's authorized

    token.transferOwnership(newOwner);
}
```

Comment: assuming the token contract `transferOwnership` function has the usual `onlyOwner` type modifier, wouldn't `msg.sender` of this call have to be the crowdsale contract address in this case?

Comment: Yes, `msg.sender` in the token contract's `transferOwnership` will be the crowdsale contract, since the crowdsale contract is what's calling the function.

Comment: Am i right in thinking this will only work where the crowdsale contract has the `Ownable` interface? i.e. if it hadn't imported the `Ownable` contract it wouldn't be able to make this call?

Comment: This will work as long as `token` is of a type that defines `transferOwnership`. There are no requirements on the crowdsale contract.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, much appreciated!

@Papi Junior, you should accept smarx's answer given that it worked - standard StackExchange behaviour :)